# Logs displaying as system.err and system.info in Google cloud dataflow after migrating to Apache beam 2.46.0

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, slf4j

I have upgraded the Apache beam version to 2.46.0. Using slf4j for logs display.versiom of slf4j is 2.0.7.

After upgrade all my logs are using system.err as logger in gcp worker logs console of dataflow.

I am getting a warning, Please use a logger instead of system.err or system.out. Please switch to using org.slf4j.logger. I have slf4j dependency in classpath as well.

Could you please suggest what can be done to display logs using slf4j for dataflow.

I didn't find any options to take slf4j instead of system.out and system.err